# CSS formatting for paper printing?

Tags: html, css, printing

Do css @page or @print work anymore?

Been trying -- off and on for years -- find ways of fluently converting web pages for paper printing.  Beyond using a lot of careful and meticulous non-standard CSS and JS I haven't found any standards to make it a more coherent process.
I've never been able to make use of @page and @print -- no browsers seem to respond to it.

Among the pages I've been testing with: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

Is it something I'm missing, or have things changed?
Are there newer more modern approaches that might be more effective?

Comment: My hopes get up about 2 twice a year... and then I loose a week of my R&D life.

Comment: Hah.  Brilliant!!  I'm not alone.  Thanks for the perspective.   I noticed on Safari on both Mac and iOS there's "experimental' at-page" support, suggesting it's most definitely a work in progress and hardly universal.